# Use Excel as back-end database to build chart in report builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I need to build a chart using Report Builder 2.0 OR 3.0 (version yet not decided) but my database is excel. Is it possible to construct chart with an excel as a database?

**UPDATE**: I selected ODBC as my datasource and selected the desired excel sheet and test the connection. The connection was successful. But then why it asking for an SQL Query?

DataSource created with Excel as backend

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixFJM.png

Why it is prompting this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0J4F.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bifuture.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssrs-building-report-on-excel.html

Comment: Please [provide context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for the link you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

Using Excel as a database in my opinion is not a good idea, but if you have to... Report Builder probably can utilize ODBC - try establishing an ODBC with your Excel database, then use it as your data source for Report Builder.

Comment: I tried ODBC with the Excel, but why does it asks to enter me a SQL Query in that?

Comment: because it "simulate" sql database

Comment: Try to build a query - it looks like a visual query builder... Maybe start with a small xls test file as a first step.

Comment: How to build a Query? Yes, i have started with small xls test file only that has 4-5 records

Comment: How i can a SQL Query from excel file?

Comment: I never did this with with Report Builder. Maybe try with SELECT * FROM nameofworksheet;

Comment: That doesn't works!  I tried that before posting question here :-)

Comment: http://bifuture.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssrs-building-report-on-excel.html-- One in ALL

Comment: not the name of worksheet, it is the name of the tab in the worksheet. Say Sheet1$, Sheet2$

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `select * from [sheet1$]` to extract the data. Sheet1 can be replaced with your sheet name (as on the worksheet tab).